# Applied Energistics Subnetwork doesn't accept items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

I created an mob farm using cursed earth and an auto-spawner spawning endermen, their drops I want to collect in an AE subnetwork.

The mobfarm consists of 2 grinders and an iron tank. The grinders output their items into itemducts which lead to an ME Interface which is linked to the subnetwork.

The subnetwork is powered by an ME Power Relay and has an ME Drive, ME Controller, ME Interface and is read-only to my main network through an ME Storage Bus.

However, my grinders now refuse to work and the itemducts are clogged up, meaning my AE subsystem doesn't accept the items... which is weird considering they're not partitioned.

[image: Clogged itemduct]

When looking at the itemduct to the ME Interface, items just bounce back and forth in the last itemduct.

**This seemed to be a graphical glitch, restarting the server helped this**

[image: Bouncing items in itemduct]

Does anyone happen to know why this happens? And possibly how to fix it?

Using a second ME Interface did nothing.

Comment: Does breaking the itemduct and replacing the servo help?  I've noticed they sometimes get clogged up during construction and need refreshing.

Comment: I tried that multiple times, but no avail. At this point, I placed chests behind the grinders and used another chest next to the sub network acting as a buffer. All accepted items are imported into the network and the 'blacklisted' (whitelisted on a servo) are trashed (bows, armor etc). All in all, I'm trying to, more or less, replicate what direwolf did in ‎S6E64, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6UyrTxEKp0.

Comment: The ME interface can be weird about accepting items, especially from itemducts. You did the right thing using a chest as a buffer, as both AE and TE recognise these as valid inputs/outputs.